# Can't import android.support.v7 (appcompat) - Unresolved Library

Tags: android, gradle, import, build.gradle, libraries

I tried to import this support library into my project but can't get it to work.

First of all I can't find it. When I hit the + button on the Dependencies tab and search for it. I have found android.support.v4 but I need v7 as well.
I read somewhere that the library might be deprecated.

So in my code it can't import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
The v7 is in Red because, it can't be resolved.
I followed the direction on how to add a library. But still can't solve the issue. I did normal steps as clean, sync gradle files, invalidate links, etc...

Here is some of my code from mainactivity

```
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuItem
    //import androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    //import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat
    //import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
    //import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
    //import android.widget.ShareActionProvider



    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private var shareActionProvider : ShareActionProvider? = null

    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuItem
    //import androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    //import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat
    //import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
    //import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
    //import android.widget.ShareActionProvider


    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private var shareActionProvider : ShareActionProvider? = null

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        }

        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu : Menu): Boolean {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
            val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share) as MenuItem
            shareActionProvider = MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem) as ShareActionProvider
            setShareActionIntent("Want to join me for pizza?")
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        }

        private fun setShareActionIntent(text : String) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type = "text/plain"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
            shareActionProvider!!.setShareIntent(intent)
        }

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item : MenuItem) : Boolean {
            when(item.itemId) {
                R.id.action_create_order -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, OrderActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                }
                else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
}
}
```

This my gradle.build file

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url '../pluginrepo' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta05'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app (build.gradle) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gandalf.bitsandpizza"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
    //    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.+'
    //    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.+'
}
```

This is based on Refactoring suggested in answer.

The issue is now resolved. This is the updated gradle.build file from app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.some.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use this instead: import android.widget.ShareActionProvider; or this one : import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;

Comment: So if I use the aforementioned import instead of v7. Then this line of code won't work, because it can't find getActionProvider.           shareActionProvider = MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem) as ShareActionProvider

Comment: What is in red?

Comment: getActionProvider

Comment: See my update on my answer

Comment: @ConnectionistSystems Now you have duplicate imports. Remove them all and import them again with the appcompat. It should work then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using these dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

There imports

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
```

And there's no red.

Try to clean the code as well

As @Mohsen said, you can also try to do this

[image]

Comment: For the first option v7 can't be resolved. For the second option getActionProvider is unresolved reference.     shareActionProvider = MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem) as ShareActionProvider

Comment: Yes, because you didn't migrated to `AndroidX` that's why. Check the OP's `Activity` imports of `Toolbar` and `AppCompat`. I've tried to explain them all in my answer, please check that too.

Comment: Then @ConnectionistSystems make sure you have Android Studio 3.2 and then Refactor to AppCompat

Comment: Okay. I did migrate to AppCompat as suggested. I still have red on v7 which is why I tired to use AndroidX instead. I also did clean and sync gradle file.

Comment: What is red? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I uploaded an image in original question. I don't know how to do it here.

Comment: Remove your import of Androidx AppCompatActivity it should be only this one :import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity And make sure your gradle is like my answer the same implementations

Comment: Tried it @ConnectionistSystems?

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their assistance. I tired what was suggested. I changed my gradle file as was suggested and cleaned the project. It is still the same and the biggest issue is v7 is still red. I tried to refactor to AppCompat again, still nothing changed.

Comment: Did you remove the androidx import?

Comment: I uploaded two more images at the bottom of the question

Comment: Change this line testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" aswell... can you upload your code to github or something so I can take a look deeply? or maybe TeamViewer

Comment: I changed the gradle.build file. I also uploaded to github.  https://github.com/ConnectionistSystems/BitsandPizza   Thank You!

Comment: Ok, I did some changes, it's working now, you can see in the commit what I've changed... it was lot of stuff hahaha :D

Comment: Oh I'm not able to push, can you invite me ?

Comment: nvm I'll create a new project and upload it and then you can download and see what's different from yours

Comment: Hello @Skizo-ozᴉʞS  Thanks for looking at the code. I wanted to add to the repository but I don't know your email address. I tried implementing the changes you did. I see how you made changes mainly to MainActivity. I still however have the same issue. The V7 is red. Please see the latest image attached with the question. I can't find appcompatv7 to download. Perhaps you have it already downloaded in Android Studio. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @ConnectionistSystems Give me your email and I'll update your code, I did not change only the MainActivity....

Comment: The issue is now resolved. This is the updated build.gradle file. Thanks @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation, therefore I can't up/like any of the posted answers. Thanks!

Comment: But you do not need reputation to mark my answer as a correct. Feel free to upvote and mark my answer as a correct if it worked!

Answer (score 2):

> So in my code it can't import
>   android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider The v7 is in Red
>   because, it can't be resolved

I wish that was the only issue in your codes. You've added:

```
implementation 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.+' // Use specific version like 28.0.0 in future for this
```

Which refers to `v4` and `v7` `AppCompat` but your `Toolbar` and the tests + `ConstraintLayout` **are using `AndroidX`** dependencies. This is actually weird and confusing even to me!

For using [**`ShareActionProvider`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider) which is available with **`AppCompat`**, you'll need to make sure your app is migrated to `AndroidX` or not first!

I believe this is happening because it seems like your project is migrated to `AndroidX` and this is confusing the IDE to use `AppCompat` or `AndroidX`.

Simply, go to `Refactor`, Select `migrate to AppCompat` if you're trying to use V7 dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of headache. I found the issue was the Android Studio version that I was using. I was using a Beta version and for some reason the libraries were messed up. When I switched to stable version everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1) Just press on ALT+ENT and select Migrate App to AppCompat.

2) ImageView is rename to AppCompatImageView .

3) Press on ALT+ENT to import class finaly.
   problem solved !

Or do import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these in **gradle.properties**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
```